# Why am I getting this error saying too many values to unpack (expected 2 ) while uploading a document in Rossum API?

Tags: python, python-requests, valueerror

So, I am trying to upload a document to Rossum storage using python requests and I have tried the exact same code as in https://developers.rossum.ai/docs/python-for-uploading-data-in-rossum-api

```
import requests

username = "username"
password = "password"
queue_id = "123456"
path = "D:/Downloads/INV001.jpg"

url = "https://api.elis.rossum.ai/v1/queues/%s/upload" % queue_id

with open(path, "rb") as f:
    print(f)
    response = requests.post(
    url,
    files={"content", f},
    auth=(username,password),
    )
    #print(response)
annotation_url = response.json()["results"][0]["annotation"]
print("The file is reachable at the following URL:", annotation_url)
```

When I run this code, I get an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-106d2c5cb00a> in <module>
     13     url,
     14     files={"content", f},
---> 15     auth=(username,password),
     16     )
     17     #print(response)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    114     """
    115 
--> 116     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    117 
    118 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    517             hooks=hooks,
    518         )
--> 519         prep = self.prepare_request(req)
    520 
    521         proxies = proxies or {}

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in prepare_request(self, request)
    460             auth=merge_setting(auth, self.auth),
    461             cookies=merged_cookies,
--> 462             hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
    463         )
    464         return p

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare(self, method, url, headers, files, data, params, auth, cookies, hooks, json)
    314         self.prepare_headers(headers)
    315         self.prepare_cookies(cookies)
--> 316         self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
    317         self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
    318 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare_body(self, data, files, json)
    502             # Multi-part file uploads.
    503             if files:
--> 504                 (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
    505             else:
    506                 if data:

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in _encode_files(files, data)
    139                          v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, str) else v))
    140 
--> 141         for (k, v) in files:
    142             # support for explicit filename
    143             ft = None

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I have tried a lot of things like

```
f = {'image': (name_img,img,'multipart/form-data',{'Expires': '0'}) }
```

and

```
f = {'image': open(path, 'rb')}
```

Any idea to fix this error. **FYI Iam trying to upload a jpg**

Comment: In `{"content", f}` you should have a `:` instead of the `,`.

Comment: When I changed that, I got a json error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-695cec666cfa> in <module>
     18 #print(response.json())
     19 
---> 20 annotation_url = response.json()["results"][0]["annotation"]
     21 print("The file is reachable at the following URL:", annotation_url)

KeyError: 'results'


in print(response.json()), i get {'detail': 'Not found.'}

Comment: Congratulations, you have advanced to the next error.

Comment: can u help me ?

Comment: oh is that so ? ok. I learn new things every day

Comment: Had the same, was using `,` rather than `:`. I spent 4 hours on this >.< . Thanks @KlausD.